# Entity Framework metadata information POCO Types

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I am using EF 4.0 with POCO.

I am trying to to get metdata information from the conceptual model. I was able to use the MetadataWorkspace's GetItems() method to get metadata information from the conceptual model, but all types returned are Edm Types.

Does the conceptual model contain information about the actual POCO types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. It contains information about entity types and convention (same class name, same properties names and accessibility) is used to map POCO to entities.